# RxJS takeUntil doesn't unsubscribe

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I want to unsubscribe  in declarative style with "takeUntil" operator. But that's basically does't work. I can see console output anyway.

```
const unsubscribe = new Subject();

function printFoo() {
  of('foo')
    .pipe(takeUntil(unsubscribe))
    .subscribe(console.log) // Why I can see 'foo' in the  console?
}

function onDestroy() {
  unsubscribe.next();
  unsubscribe.complete();
}

onDestroy()
setTimeout(() => printFoo(), 200)
```

StaackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-svfkxg?file=index.ts

**P.S.** I expected that even `unsubscribe.next()` would be enough to unsubscribe, but even with `unsubscribe.complete()` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `onDestroy()` before the chain with `takeUntil` is even created.

When you eventually call `printFoo()` the previous emissions to `unsubscribe` won't be re-emited and the Subject `unsubscribe` is already completed anyway so `takeUntil` in this case will never complete the chain.

Answer (score 2):

Because the Subject emits before `printFoo` subscription.

After you subscribe there are no more Subject emittions.

You could use BehaviorSubject instead, since it holds the emitted values (the last 
 emitted value):

`const unsubscribe = new BehaviorSubject(false);`

```
function printFoo() {
  of('foo')
    .pipe(takeUntil(unsubscribe.pipe(filter(value => !!value)))) // Don't unsub if it's false emitted
    .subscribe(console.log)
}
```

```
function onDestroy() {
  unsubscribe2.next(true); // Emit true to cancel subscription
}
```